# При клике вне меню, закрывать его..уже голову сломала..ток начила изучать js ..пока сложно(

Tags: html, jquery

```js
function burgerMenu(selector) {
  let menu = $(selector);
  let button = menu.find('.burger-menu_button', '.burger-menu_lines');
  let links = menu.find('.burger-menu_link');
  let overlay = menu.find('.burger-menu_overlay');

  button.on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleMenu();
  });

  links.on('click', () => toggleMenu());
  overlay.on('click', () => toggleMenu());

  function toggleMenu() {
    menu.toggleClass('burger-menu_active');

    if (menu.hasClass('burger-menu_active')) {
      $('body').css('overlow', 'hidden');
    } else {
      $('body').css('overlow', 'visible');
    }
  }
}

burgerMenu('.burger-menu');
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-btn>span,
.menu-btn>span::before,
.menu-btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu-btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menubox {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
  color: black;
}

#menu-toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menubox {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger-menu">
  <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu-btn" for="menu-toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  <ul class="menubox">
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Головна</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Про Нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Блог</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Архіви</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Контакти</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно я делаю как-то так:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e){
    var div = document.querySelector('.some-class');
    if (div !== e.target && !div.contains(e.target)) {
        div.classList.remove('opened');
    }
});
```

То есть, клик не по нужному элементу что-то там закрывает.

P.S. В вопрос не вникал, это скорее общий ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по стилям, меню открывается, когда активен чекбокс. Значит порядок действий такой:

- Необходимо повесить обработчик клика на `document`, в котором нужно делать чекбокс неактивным.
- Поскольку события имеют свойство [всплывать](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing), при таком подходе при нажатии на меню вышеописанное событие тоже будет срабатывать. Значит нам нужно прервать всплытие, чтобы оно не дошло до `document`, через [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Пример:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.burger-menu');
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-toggle');


menu.onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.onclick = (e) => {
  btn.checked = false;
}
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-btn>span,
.menu-btn>span::before,
.menu-btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu-btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menubox {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
  color: black;
}

#menu-toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu-btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menubox {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger-menu">
  <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu-btn" for="menu-toggle">
                      <span></span>
                    </label>
  <ul class="menubox">
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Головна</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Про Нас</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Блог</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Архіви</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Контакти</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: я похоже слишком тупая....не получилось